# Creating a new column of a pandas dataframe:

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have this pandas dataframe called `cica_df`:

```
Fecha     |Administradora_descrip|Fondo_descrip|PUC_Codigo|PUC_Descrip|Saldo_Cuenta|CRNCY|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2007-01-31|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.517769e+11|COP  |
2007-01-31|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.386133e+12|COP  |
2007-01-31|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |3.517769e+11|COP  |
2007-01-31|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |7.386133e+12|COP  |
2007-02-28|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.897769e+11|COP  |
2007-02-28|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.986133e+12|COP  |
2007-02-28|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.907769e+11|COP  |
2007-02-28|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.766133e+12|COP  |
```

And I need to create a new column I need to create a new column whose values are the value of the column "Account_Balance" such that in the column "PUC_Code" the value is 100000 for all columns that have the same value in the columns Date, Admin_descrip, Fund_descrip and CRNCY. So I can get a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
Fecha     |Administradora_descrip|Fondo_descrip|PUC_Codigo|PUC_Descrip|Saldo_Cuenta|CRNCY|Nav        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2007-01-31|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.517769e+11|COP|4.517769e+11 |
2007-01-31|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.386133e+12|COP|4.517769e+11 |
2007-01-31|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |3.517769e+11|COP|3.517769e+11 |
2007-01-31|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |7.386133e+12|COP|3.517769e+11 |
2007-02-28|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.897769e+11|COP|4.897769e+11 |
2007-02-28|Colfondos               |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.986133e+12|COP|4.897769e+11 |
2007-02-28|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |100000  |ACTIVO     |4.907769e+11|COP|4.907769e+11 |
2007-02-28|Skandia                 |Largo Plazo  |162800  |DEPOSITO   |6.766133e+12|COP|4.907769e+11 |
```

I tried whit this code:

```
cica_df['Nav'] = np.where(cica_df['PUC_Codigo'] == 100000, cica_df['Saldo_Cuenta'], cica_df['Saldo_Cuenta'])
```

but it only repeated the column "Saldo_Cuenta". What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function in pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Group by the specified columns and calculate the account balance for PUC_Code == 100000
cica_df['Nav'] = cica_df.groupby(['Fecha', 'Administradora_descrip', 'Fondo_descrip', 'CRNCY'])['Saldo_Cuenta'].transform(
    lambda x: x.loc[x['PUC_Codigo'] == 100000].iloc[0])

print(cica_df)
```